# Why SharePoint Icon is not visible in Office 365?

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365

When I log in to Office 365, I am unable to see SharePoint Icon there. Only a few Icons I am able to see like Power Automate, etc. I am having admin rights. **Is that mean we don't have a SharePoint subscription or something?**

[image]

To confirm the above, I checked it in my Admin center as below at 2 locations. i.e. Licenses, Products,

1. Login 365 --> Click Admin Icon --> Click Billing --> Click Licence (Its showing Power automate Free & **E5 Trial** licence **Expired with status deleted**)

[image]

2. Login 365 --> Click Admin Icon --> Click Billing -->Click Your Products(It shows Power automate Free-Status- Active)

[image]

**What should we do in this case? are we having SharePoint?  Please help.**

Thank you.

Comment: Which license are you using (like E1, E3, E5, etc.)? Are you M365/tenant administrator?

Comment: @GaneshSanap, Yes, I am a Tenant admin.  & M365 E5 developer trail. Subscription status = deleted, Expiration date=7/7/2022, Unit price=Free trial

Comment: Were you able to access SharePoint before your sandbox expired? If you don't use your tenant for longer time, it gets expired. check: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/developer-program/subscription-expiration-and-renewal

Comment: @GaneshSanap for more than half a year, I'm not using this, from 6 to 7 months and subscription shows deleted. what should I do?

Comment: I don't think you will be able to renew it now. You need to create a new developer subscription with new name. Was there any data in SharePoint? You must have received emails related to subscription expiration (you might have missed those).